# Linking on 0 or more missing data fields update

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have 2 tables, a list of Offices I have and a list of Income to apportion to the offices

```
create table #Income(City varchar(50),Office varchar(50),YearsBudget money)
insert #Income
select 'London', null,     5000 UNION
select 'Paris',  null,     6000 UNION
select null,    'Sales',   7000 UNION
select 'London','Support',10000

create table #Offices(City varchar(50),Office varchar(50),Ratio float)
insert #Offices
select 'London','Research Lab'     ,.15 UNION
select 'London','Customer Services',.45 UNION
select 'London','Sales'            ,.05 UNION
select 'London','Admin'            ,.19 UNION
select 'London','Support'          ,.17 UNION
select 'Paris' ,'Sales'            ,.15 UNION
select 'Paris' ,'Admin'            ,.45 UNION
select 'Paris' ,'Support'          ,.05 UNION
select 'Madrid','Sales'            ,.45 UNION
select 'Madrid','Research Lab'     ,.25
```

For example, in 1 row of my data from #Income I have £5000 which I have to apportion to all known London offices, in in another row I have £6000 which I need to apportion to all known Paris offices

This can be achieved in the following SQL

```
select o.City,o.Office, convert(money,i.YearsBudget/DATA.RSum*o.Ratio) as ThisYearsBudget
from #Income as i
Left Join #Offices as O
on i.City=o.City
Left join (select child.City,SUM(child.Ratio) as RSum from #Offices as child group by child.City ) DATA
ON i.city=DATA.City 
where i.Office is null
```

For apportioning of £7000 to all sales offices and £10000 to the London Support office would need a further 2 select statements and a further select statement to sum and group the results for the 3 apportioning views.  Can I achieve this in a one simple view?

Comment: If you add all the **`Ratio`** for **LONDON** it comes to **1.01**, which should not be.

Comment: Which SQL Server version? 2005+?

Comment: The field Ratio is used for apportioning data and is not related in any way to a percentage.  E.G. When The apportioning data for 'Research Lab' ( which has a total ratio of .40) 62.5% goes to Madrid and 37.5 to London

Comment: The version of SQL server is 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample Data**:

```
create table Income(City varchar(50),Office varchar(50),YearsBudget money)
insert Income
select 'London', null,     5000 UNION
select 'Paris',  null,     6000 UNION
select null,    'Sales',   7000 UNION
select 'London','Support',10000;

create table Offices(City varchar(50),Office varchar(50),Ratio float)
insert Offices
select 'London','Research Lab'     ,.15 UNION
select 'London','Customer Services',.45 UNION
select 'London','Sales'            ,.05 UNION
select 'London','Admin'            ,.19 UNION
select 'London','Support'          ,.17 UNION
select 'Paris' ,'Sales'            ,.15 UNION
select 'Paris' ,'Admin'            ,.45 UNION
select 'Paris' ,'Support'          ,.05 UNION
select 'Madrid','Sales'            ,.45 UNION
select 'Madrid','Research Lab'     ,.25;
```

**Query**:

```
   select o.City,
          o.Office,
          ThisYearsBudget = SUM(convert(money,sq.YearsBudget*o.Ratio/sq.totalratio))
     from Offices o
     join (
          select i.city, i.office, i.yearsbudget, totalratio = sum(o.ratio)
            from income i
            join offices o on isnull(i.city,o.city)=o.city
                          and isnull(i.office,o.office)=o.office
        group by i.city, i.office, i.yearsbudget
          ) sq on isnull(sq.city,o.city)=o.city
              and isnull(sq.office,o.office)=o.office
 group by grouping sets ((o.City, o.Office)
                         --,() -- uncomment this line to see grand total
                        )
 order by City, Office;
```

**Results**:

```
|   CITY |            OFFICE | THISYEARSBUDGET |
------------------------------------------------
| London |             Admin |        940.5941 |
| London | Customer Services |       2227.7228 |
| London |      Research Lab |        742.5743 |
| London |             Sales |        785.9863 |
| London |           Support |      10841.5842 |
| Madrid |             Sales |       4846.1538 |
|  Paris |             Admin |       4153.8462 |
|  Paris |             Sales |            3000 |
|  Paris |           Support |        461.5385 |
```

### SQL Fiddle Demo